# Grails: Testing GORM criteria that require properties mapped by user-type (org.joda.time.DateTime)

Tags: testing, grails, grails-orm, jodatime, spock

I'm trying to test a method that uses a Criteria query to count matching object.  This uses my `Reservation` domain class that has a property of type `org.joda.time.DateTime`

```
class Reservation {
  Organization organization
  DateTime dateTime
  //...

  int countPending(Organization org) {
    Reservation.createCriteria().count() {
      eq("organization", org)
      gte("dateTime", new DateTime())
      // ...
    } 
  }
}
```

Here is the specification I use to test that method:

```
@TestFor(Reservation)
class ReservationSpec extends Specification {
  def "countPending should return the number of pending reservations"() {
    // ...
    expect:
    Reservation.countPending(org) == 0;
  }
}
```

When I try to run the test, I get:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property [dateTime] is not a valid property of class [Reservation]`

I suspect this is because DateTime is neither a primitive type or a domain object, and the code that mocks domain objects doesn't know how to handle it.  In order to run this code in the application we use a custom user-type mapping (`org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime`).

Is there a way to make DateTime known to the domain mocking code, or any other way to make this testable?

EDIT: Changed `@Mock([Reservation])` to `@TestFor(Reservation)` -- the result is the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762321/grails-controller-unit-tests-with-joda-time  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130838/in-grails-is-there-a-good-way-to-mock-the-current-time-using-joda-time

Comment: I'm already using the second answer (DateTimeUtils.currentMillisFixed) to set the time.  It's the GORM criteria that's having issue with a properti IT thinks doesn't exist.

Comment: If your spec is testing your domain class, replace @Mock([Resevation]) for @TestFor(Reservation)

Comment: Thanks.  You're right.  I made the change, but the result is the same.

Comment: For things Hibernate specific I think you will have to use hibernate in your test instead of the mock gorm impl